# Turning Only Specific Letters of the name of a file to Uppercase with bash script

Tags: bash

I need to rename a file by turning only some of the letters to uppercase.

E.g:

```
filename: cookies.txt

letters to be changed: c,k

filename final: CooKies.txt
```

All this should be done with a bash script.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial to do in `bash` with a `bash`-specific [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) form:

```
filename=cookies.txt
echo "${filename^^[ck]}"
# To actually rename a file:
# mv "$filename" "${filename^^[ck]}"
```

will uppercase every c and k in the expansion of `$filename`.

You can also use `${variable^pattern}` to only uppercase the first character that matches `pattern`, and commas instead of carets to do lowercasing. Leaving out the pattern will convert the entire string (Or first character).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP specifically said they're looking for a bash solution.

Comment: That's true, I guess the best course is to clean up their tags. Regardless you got my +1.

Comment: In `zsh`, you can use the less elegant `echo "$filename:gs/c/C/:gs/k/K/"`, or `$filename:u` to uppercase the entire string.